# Scoring predictions in sklearn (Python machine learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm going through the following IPython Notebook which analyzes the [Iris dataset](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rhiever/Data-Analysis-and-Machine-Learning-Projects/blob/master/example-data-science-notebook/Example%20Machine%20Learning%20Notebook.ipynb)

At one point in the notebook the author builds the following model:

[image]

At this point, I became very confused. What is going on in the last line?
From what I learned, you should create a prediction based on the model and then compare that prediction to the `y_test` values.

I would have done the following:

```
predictions = decision_tree_classifier.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print classification_report(y_test, predictions)
```

What is going on when the author generates a score based on the `testing_inputs` and the `testing_classes`?

Comment: It would be a better idea to ask your question in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.score):

> ***score(X, y, sample_weight=None)***
>
> Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

And that's exactly what it does. It internally carries out prediction on `X_test`, generates `y_pred` and compares it to `y_test` to compute an accuracy score.

What you do is similar, but in two steps. You first predict and then compare to `y_test`. In addition, you are printing out the precision, recall and f1-score.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit of detail to @Coldspeed's answer, the `score` for `DecisionTreeClassifier` calls [`sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L112).  This is the **percentage of classifications made correctly**.  Only pointing this out because I don't find "mean accuracy" all that intuitive.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3]
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3]

accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
Out[106]: 0.5
```